# Swift with iOS 5 deployment target

Tags: ios, swift

What is the minimum deployment target for Xcode 6 and the new Swift language?  Specifically, can I still support iOS 5.0?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I tried as well as I could, and it works in the 8.0 and 7.1 simulators as well as on my 7.1.1 device, but I don't have an iOS 5 device anymore.

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to support a version of iOS you can't test with. If you don't have an iOS 5 device or you can't install an iOS 5 simulator, don't support iOS 5. What's the point anyway?

Comment: From what I've read, Swift will be supported for iOS7+.

Comment: iOS 5 will be excluded, I think.

Comment: WTF?  iOS 5 is 2 years old!

Comment: @LeeArmstrong: Apps submitted for the app store can still target iOS 4.3

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[From one of the engineers working on Swift](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/473539096065736705), iOS 7, Mavericks and later:

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-apps-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower?rq=1 - it conflicts with this answer.

Comment: I test the Swift sample code in iPad4 iOS6.0, it works.

Comment: So does app written is Swift work in iOS 6? It would be great, because there are so many users with iOS 6.

Comment: Remember that this is Beta 1. I'm sure support for < iOS 7 on compile time is going to be dropped in future Betas.

Comment: @riven it may work But that's not safe http://stackoverflow.com/a/26408879/730807 and by the way the xcode also can target from iOS 7 only.

Answer (score 21):

Swift is supported on devices running iOS 7 or later.

Comment: Is it supported on devices below iOS 7? What about iOS 5? Or did you mean "is supported *only* on devices running iOS 7?

Comment: No,it's compatible with iOS 6, it uses the same compiler and outputs the same binary

Comment: I understand that. But it's possible that Swift is supported on devices running iOS 7 or later *and* on devices running iOS and earlier, but you haven't said anything about the latter.

Comment: It does not output the same binaries as it requires some Objective-C runtime additions that were added by Apple engineers only starting with iOS 7.

Comment: @user334856 Interpreting Dave's statement using formal logic, yes, Dave is making no statement about whether any iOS version ≤6 is or isn't supported.  However, in regular human language _(which Dave is using here)_, it can be implied that the context of Dave's statement is the entire range of iOS versions supporting Swift— so Dave's statement lists all the versions that _do_ support Swift, leaving all versions not listed as unsupported.  Put another way, Dave is implying iOS versions ≤6 do not support Swift by not mentioning them.  _Context is everything._