# How to make a objective-c written iOS app containing a swift-written app extension while still supporting iOS 6?

Tags: ios6, swift, ios8, app-store-connect, ios-app-extension

Is that even possible?

I made an archive, validated & pushed it to itunes connect and I got a mail saying:

```
Invalid Deployment Target - Apps built with Swift must have a Deployment Target of 7.0 or later.
```

I get that swift is not supported on iOS 6 but since extensions are not either, doing this should be possible no?

The containing app itself is still entirely written in Objective-C.

I'm aware that extensions are available only on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extension is a new feature in iOS 8 and it does not support iOS 7 and below. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1
2. Your app extension is written in swift. And Swift only support iOS 7+. See [Swift with iOS 5 deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007050/swift-with-ios-5-deployment-target)

So the answer is not possible. It also doesn't matter if your project is written in objective-c because of the above reasons.

**Updated**: it's probably good to just follow the instruction from iTunes connect to get your app approved.