# Will code written in Swift work on iOS 7 and earlier?

Tags: ios, swift

As stated, after the release of iOS 8, will I be able to write code in Swift and have it working on iOS 7? Or will it work on iOS 8 only?

If your answer is "yes, it will work on iOS 7 and earlier", I have another question:

How will iOS 7 and earlier know the syntax of Swift and have those faster capabilities? (Or am I missing some basic knowledge about how apps are compiled?)

Comment: it is the compiler that need to know the syntax, not the OS. But I don't know if apple let us compile swift for iOS 7 or below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-apps-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They will work on iOS 7, but not earlier versions.