# Swift and App Store approval

Tags: swift

Do the Apple App Store guidelines approve of submitting an app that uses Swift right now?

Swift can run on all [devices running iOS 7.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-apps-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower), so if I submit an app that uses Swift before iOS 8 is released will it be rejected?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the policies of a third-party site rather than actual programming.

Comment: Agreed. This is better suited to Apple Developer forums.

Answer (score 2):

Apps written in the Xcode 6 Beta will not be approved so you have to wait for the new Xcode to be released before submitting apps with Swift code

Answer (score 1):

To submit with Swift you'll have to build your app with the iOS 8 SDK, even if you want to target devices running iOS 7. Apple are not accepting submissions built with the iOS 8 SDK, and probably won't for some time (until the SDK goes GM).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you'd have to use XCode 6 (which is beta), iOS8 base SDK (which is beta), and that the language itself is likely to undergo significant revisions & changes between now and public release, I'd say it'd almost certainly be rejected.