# What's the best way to detect if Swift is supported in the current Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

Is there a better way to detect if Swift is supported in the current Xcode project than checking for iOS 8 or OSX 10.10?

`#if defined(__IPHONE_8_0) || defined(__MAC_10_10)`

I have a mixed Swift/Objective-C codebase with two different Xcode projects.

Comment: Why do you need to check this? Swift is interoperable with Objective-C.

Comment: Note that you do not need `iOS 8` or `10.9` to use Swift. You can use at least `iOS 6` and `10.4`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-apps-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower

Comment: Yes the resulting binaries will run on iOS 6 and 10.4, but iOS 8 and/or OSX 10.10 should still be defined at compile time.