# Can't Run xCode 6 Beta 5 Swift App on iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xcode6-beta5

I'm trying to test my swift app on my iPhone 5 device. But I'm getting the following message:

[image]

I just updated my iPhone 5 and xCode 6 to the latest versions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue was my deployment target in build settings is 8.0, it should be 7.0 if I want my swift app to run in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run the app when it is made with swift because that comes with iOS 8. you need the beta on your iPhone
And you cannot use swift for iOS 7 programming

Comment: Actually it seems that , Swift applications compile into standard binaries and can be run on OS X 10.9 and iOS 7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower/24002461#24002461