# old mac - does it support swift in xcode 3.2.6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have developped my app on android but would like to do the dev for iOS.
I have an old mac that supports only 10.6.8 and xcode 3.2.6.
I can get access from time to time on a mac with 10.10.
my understanding is that the way to go now is swift.
will my xcode 3.2.6 support swift so that I could developp on my old mac and test on the newest 10.10.
what do you recommend I do? buying a new mac? :)

Many thanks!

Comment: NO - swift language is not available in Xcode 3.2.6

Answer (score 2):

Swift is only supported on [xCode 6 like you can read here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/132682) [And only for iOS 7 and higher.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002461/1141395)

So even methods are available for iOS 2, as long as the devices don't have installed iOS 7 or higher the swift code can't be executed and you would need to use objective-c instead.

Comment: thanks! and I suppose that you confirm: swift is the way to go?

Comment: I started with java before programming objective-c. It is a really strong method and looks more familiar to java. And in some parts you have way more possiblities to do things than you have it in other languages, so get on it. It also looks like there shouldn't be a problem to reach many users as most of iPhone users already updated to iOS 8. But you might lose some of the users who can't update or don't want to update and maybe won't be able to use your app.