# Sticking with Swift 1 and making app for IOS7 and above

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have few questions that I was considering while making an app. The app supports ios7 and above. Its being written in swift 1.2 and I came across few articles that it's better to switch the code to Swift 2. The problem is some frameworks that is being used does not support swift 2 just yet.

1) Is it possible to stick with swift 1.2 and continue deploying for iOS 7 and above?

2) Once Xcode 7 is official, do we need to update all the code to Swift 2 or can continue with Swift 1.2 for some time until all the frameworks upgraded to Swift 2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't have to switch to Swift 2 immediately, but you have to stick with Xcode 6 and there's some inconvenience such as not being able to test on iOS9.

2) It's easy to upgrade Swift 1.2 code to Swift 2, my opinion is to wait until the frameworks support Swift 2.

Good luck!

Comment: Swift 1 does support iOS 7. In fact so does Swift 2. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825638/swift-2-0-minimum-system-version-requirement-deployment-target