# Export OS X app compatible with older versions

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am practicing swift for OS X, and I'd like to show my boyfriend what I made. I found how to export the app from Xcode 6, and it runs just fine on my computer with OS X 10.10. However, after sending it to my boyfriend, he gets a "not compatible with this OS X version" message. What do I need to do in my app, so he can run it too?

UPDATE: 
I have read this [Do Swift-based applications work on OS X 10.9/iOS 7 and lower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower) which doesn't help my current problem.

I found how to change deployment target, and now he gets it to show in dock, but no window is showing. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of OS X does he have? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower

Comment: He has 10.9. I saw that, but it's not whether or not it's compatible overall, I know it is, it's how I make it to work on his computer.

Comment: Did you set the deployment target to 10.9, by default its 10.10

Comment: Yes I did, it only starts the app, but no window is coming up

Comment: @Ahana Does your project use storyboards? Mac storyboards are supported on OS X 10.10 and later. They are not supported on 10.9.

Comment: Yes it does use storyboard, but why does that matter in the finished product?

Comment: @Ahana It matters because storyboards are a technology that does not exist on 10.9. It's the same situation as Swift code not being supported in OS X 10.8, 10.7, and earlier. If you want to support 10.9, use xib files.

Comment: Thank you, can you please add it as an answer to I can mark it answered? :)

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk Is there any way I can just convert the current project I have, or do I have to redo it?

Comment: @Ahana I recommend starting with a new project. You could add a xib file to your project, but you're going to have to recreate the user interface in the xib file and fiddle with Xcode settings to use the xib file instead of the storyboard. For a small project it's easier to start with a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your app does not work on 10.9 is because it uses storyboards. Apple added Mac storyboards in OS X 10.10. A project that uses storyboards will not run in 10.9. If you want to support 10.9, use xib files instead of storyboards.