# iOS : Swift programming support?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I made an iOS app using swift in Xcode 7.1 beta 1 (SDK 9.1).
What range of iOS versions are supported by this configuration? Does it support iOS 4 and later?

Answer (score 0):

Swift is only supported by [Mavericks and iOS 7](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/473539096065736705) (and later) 
(author is an Apple engineer working on Swift).
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2) you can find detailed information about runtime and compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Swift code can be deployed to OS X 10.9 and iOS 7.0. It will crash at launch on older OS versions. for better please have a look of this post - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower/24038997#24038997)