# swift3.0 in ios7 crash

Tags: swift, swift3

Does **swift3.0** support **ios7**?

when i run a swift3.0 project in ios7,it crash, and shows
 dyld:

> Symbol not found: _kCLErrorUserInfoAlternateRegionKey   Referenced
>   from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/9D708DFE-C6B0-4C9A-9CEF-CB495903912D/YouKuHD.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation  in
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/9D708DFE-C6B0-4C9A-9CEF-CB495903912D/YouKuHD.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib

i cannot find doc in apple doc ,can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067678/swift-3-ios-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

No.

> Swift 3 is only compatible with iOS 8.0 and newer.

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38074273/6448167) for more about why. If you'd like to program for iOS 7, I would suggest using a previous version of Swift and subsequently a previous version of Xcode - (ie 7.3) I believe on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) they offer the option to download earlier release versions of their software.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer that links to the other answer, you should instead vote to close this question as a duplicate of that other question.