# Why can't I convert this String to a URL?

Tags: ios, swift, string, url, webview

I have x 2 questions about urls and webViews.

Question 1:
I have a string which I am getting from an API that is supposed to be a url. The string is `https://godochurch.blob.core.windows.net/sermons/1031/30-1-2017-Vision Sunday-Devotion.mp3`

When trying to convert to a url I'm getting nil.

Here is the code:

```
if let sermonUrl = sermonUrl {

        if let url = URL(string: sermonUrl) {

            let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.loadRequest(requestObj)

        }
    }
```

I have worked out that the space between 'Vision' and 'Sunday' is the problem.

Should I be encoding the string in some way before trying to convert it to a URL? What's confusing is that if I paste the string into my browser it works just fine, but I notice the browser is percent encoding the space.

If I am supposed to be encoding the string, how do I do that?

Question 2:
I see that `URL(string: "urlStringHere")` is only available from iOS 10. My app needs to work for iOS 9. How can I convert the above code so it works on iOS 9 and 10.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You already test another url with this code yet?

Comment: Yes. In fact if I manually percent encode the space for that URL the view opens fine.

Comment: Ok so cause from your url have blank space.

Comment: @SourLeangChhean i think you are simply restating what I said in my question. I am wondering if there is a standard helper method or something you are supposed to call on a string that might be a url in order to remove spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: escape that space with `%20` or `+`:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://godochurch.blob.core.windows.net/sermons/1031/30-1-2017-Vision%20Sunday-Devotion.mp3") {
    // ...
}
```

2: `URL` was introduced with Swift 3, which is compatible with iOS 8 and later. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067678/swift-3-ios-compatibility) on how to make it work with older versions of iOS.

---

**Edit:** the easiest way to percent-escape a URL is to use [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlcomponents):

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://godochurch.blob.core.windows.net")!
components.path = "/sermons/1031/30-1-2017-Vision Sunday-Devotion.mp3"

if let url = components.url {
    // ... 
}
```

If you happen to get you URL strings from a webservice and it contains a space, that service is bad. Space is not allowed in an URL. Web browsers relax that rule because they know there are bad URLs out there. Swift won't take it.

Comment: Re 1: Hmm, thats not really answering my question. I know I need to escape the space in the string, but how do I do that? Re. 2: Thanks!

Comment: @Code Different, ok, that is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: That's a neat trick. Does that approach automatically use the appropriate allowed character sets for each component of the URL?

Comment: NSURLComponents/URLComponents is a very useful class. I could have used that 10 years ago on Mac OS.

Comment: @DuncanC it automatically percent-escapes all components of a URL with the appropriate charsets

Comment: That alone is worth the price of admission. Add the ability to slice and dice URLs into components, and the ability to build URLS **from** components, and it is a real gem.